# LIKE operator for Progress DB SQL

Tags: sql, sql-like, case-statement, openedge, progress-db

I'm trying to do something like this in Progress SQL (THIS IS NOT POSTGRES!)

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN code LIKE '%foo%' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as foo
FROM
    bar
```

However Progress does not support a LIKE operator. `INSTR` looks like it might do the job, but it is a Progress extension an isn't supported on the DB I am using. Is there another way of achieving this using standard ODBC functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `LIKE` operator in the Progress 4GL.  (There is a `LIKE` keyword, but it is used for something different.)  Instead you need to use `MATCHES` or `CONTAINS` operators.  I've never used a SQL interface to Progress but it may be the same.

So you could try:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN code MATCHES '*foo*' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as foo
FROM
    bar
```

Note - `MATCHES` uses `*` for a wildcard instead of `%`.

Or:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN code CONTAINS 'foo' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as foo
FROM
    bar
```

Comment: The Opposite of MATCHES is - NOT myVariable MATCHES '*foo*'

Answer (score 1):

Just found this question and to anybody who might still have a problem with it i suggest using SquirrelSQL Client, which allows you to write almost 100% SQL syntax towards the Progress base. Like included

Answer (score 0):

You can  try with MATCHES (same syntax than LIKE) and maybe that works.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Progress are you using 10.0?  10.1?  10.2?

Are you using the embedded SQL-89 from within a 4GL session or are you using SQL-92 via an ODBC/JDBC connection?  It sounds like you are using SQL-92 since you made reference to "drivers" and INSTR.

In any event there is no LIKE for SQL.  There is INSTR and LOCATE which might do what you want though.

MATCHES is only available as a 4GL keyword.  To use it in SQL you would need to be using embedded SQL-89 but nobody in their right mind would code SQL inside a 4GL session.  It is only there as a marketing checkbox and it is a completely untenable way to write 4GL code.